# Return boolean in java?

Tags: java, boolean, return

I need help on this question.

"Inside the ChkNum class,the method inEven()return if the value that it is passed "
is Even.It return false that is odd.Therefore isEven()has a return type of boolean."

also those line below cannot be changed.

```
if(e.inEven(10))System.out.println("10 is even");

if(e.inEven(9))System.out.println("9 is even");

if(e.inEven(8))System.out.println("8 is even");"
```

i am a beginner in java. 
I try to finish this question like the following program.Anyway, it doesn't work.=(
 What was I doing wrong?

```
public class ChkNum{

boolean inEven=true;

public boolean inEven(int o)
{   
    if ((o%2)==0) { inEven = true;} 
    else  
    { inEven = false;}
        return inEven;  
       }
    ;
}

class main{
public static void main(String args[])

  {ChkNum e=new ChkNum();

    if(e.inEven(10))System.out.println("10 is even");
    if(e.inEven(9))System.out.println("9 is even");
    if(e.inEven(8))System.out.println("8 is even");


    }
}
```

Comment: Take the `return` out of the scope for `else`.

Comment: compile error? Or you put the return inside the "else"?

Answer (score 6):

If you'd indent your code, you'd find the problem:

```
public boolean inEven(int o)
{
    if ((o%2)==0) { 
        inEven = true;
    } else { 
        inEven = false;
    }
    return inEven;  
       } // remove this
    ; // remove this
}
```

It would also make more sense to make `inEven` a local variable (i.e., declare it inside the `inEven` method).

Comment: @zegkljan what can look like a magic for the OP, who has the problems with getting rid of unnecessary braces.

Answer (score 3):

```
       public class ChkNum {
            public boolean inEven(int o) {   
                   return o%2 ==0;
            }
       }
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no any specific way to return boolean value, you can return any type through the same way

**1.Boolean**

```
public boolean inEven(int o)
{
    if ((o%2)==0) { 
        inEven = true;
    }  else  { 
        inEven = false;
    }
    return inEven;  

}
```

**2.Integer**

```
public int inEven(int o)
{
    if ((o%2)==0) { 
        inEven = 1;
    }  else  { 
        inEven = 0;
    }
    return inEven;  

}
```

Like the same way for `String,Double` etc you can return any type value.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
public boolean inEven(int o)
{   
     if ((o%2)==0) { inEven = true;} 
     else  
     { inEven = false;}

     return inEven;  

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this-

```
public boolean inEven(int o)
{   
    if ((o%2)==0) 
   { 
    inEven = true;
   } 
    else  
    { 
      inEven = false;}
    }
   return inEven; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code indentation is bad why dont you make it simple and clear for yourself, you have time to be a pro and write in style..

Thats your inEven function..

```
public boolean inEven(int o)
{   
    if ((o%2)==0) { inEven = true;} 
    else  
    { inEven = false;}
        return inEven;  
     } // <- What is this doing
  ; // <-What is this doing
}
```

*Should be like :*

```
  public boolean inEven(int o)
    {   
        if ((o%2)==0)
        { 
          inEven = true;
        } 
        else  
        { 
           inEven = false;
        }
            return inEven;  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that while some of these answers work, the code can be simplified:

```
public class ChkNum {

     //boolean inEven=true;

     public boolean inEven(int o) {

        //if ((o%2)==0) {
        //    inEven= true;
        //} else {
        //    inEven = false;
        //}
        //return inEven;

        // replace the above with:
        return o % 2 == 0;
    }
}
```

This would make the code more succinct and readable. It also eliminates the need for the global variable *inEven*. The boolean expression returns a boolean already, so you can simply return that.

Here's the Test class for completeness (kept the same):

```
public class Test {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        ChkNum e = new ChkNum();
        if(e.inEven(10))System.out.println("10 is even");
        if(e.inEven(9))System.out.println("9 is even");
        if(e.inEven(8))System.out.println("8 is even");     
    }
}
```